# unique identifier in data.table

Tags: r, uniqueidentifier, data.table, stata

I have a `data.table` with 11 variables and 200,000+ rows. I am trying to find the `unique identifier` (in other words, `key`) in this `data.table`.

I am looking for something like [isid](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?isid) in Stata, which checks whether the specified variables uniquely identify the observations. Can someone please help?

Comment: The rownames are required to be unique in dataframes. You have not told us enough about the `isid` attribute in Stata to say much more. You also need to clarify whether you are using the contributed data.table package or are merely confused about the proper term for a `data.frame`.

Comment: @DWin - I am not confusing data.frame for data.table. I am using the package data.table. I was hoping someone with R and Stata knowledge to answer this question. But since you don't seem to be familiar with Stata, `isid var1 var2` checks if var1 and var2 form the key in the dataset. I am looking for something similar in R. Given a dataset with a lot of variables, I just want to assert that the key is what I think it is.

Comment: @Arun Doesn't help. Thanks though!

Comment: @user2012406, in that case, do: `all(key(DT) %in% c("var1", "var2")`

Comment: I believe you are confused about the 'key' in data.table-objects being a unique identifier.

Comment: Two questions are being mixed here. In Stata `isid` allows one _or more_ variables to be tested on whether, singly or  jointly, they act as identifier. Yet original question was about _the_ unique identifier (my emphasis). As with your previous question, I think you'd get better help from R people by putting more emphasis on the exact problem you want solved, and less emphasis on how you could do it in Stata.  I am positive about Stata; I just think your target of people fluent in R and Stata is much smaller than the pool of fluent R users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer the OP question [I haven't used the `data.table` yet], but it will help `R` only user's to answer the OP's question. My focus will be on explaining how `isid` is actually working on `Stata`. I use data from `R` database (you need to install `optmatch` for this data).

```
library(optmatch)
data(nuclearplants)
sample<-nuclearplants
```

I am focusing only on subset of data frame since my goal is to only explain what `isid` is doing:

```
sample<-sample[,c(1,2,5,10)]
head(sample,5)
 cost  date  cap cum.n
H 460.05 68.58  687    14
I 452.99 67.33 1065     1
A 443.22 67.33 1065     1
J 652.32 68.00 1065    12
B 642.23 68.00 1065    12
```

Now, when I use the `Stata` command `isid cost` it doesn't display anything which means there are no duplicate observations on cost (`R` command for this is `unique(sample$cost)` or `sample[duplicated(sample),]`

```
[1] cost  date  cap   cum.n
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names).)
```

However when we use `isid date` i.e. on date variables, `Stata` reports that it is not unique. Alternatively, if you run `duplicates date examples`, `Stata` will give you duplicate observations as follows:

```
. duplicates example date

Duplicates in terms of date

  +-------------------------------+
  | group:   #   e.g. obs    date |
  |-------------------------------|
  |      1   2         27   67.25 |
  |      2   2          2   67.33 |
  |      3   3         29   67.83 |
  |      4   2          4      68 |
  |      5   5          8   68.42 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |      6   2          1   68.58 |
  |      7   2         12   68.75 |
  |      8   3         14   68.92 |
  +-------------------------------+
```

To interpret the output, it is saying that observation 67.25 has two repeated observations (as indicated by `#`). The first observation corresponds to row 27 (it doesn't identify the row number of second duplicate with 67.25). `Group` gives the unique identifier for each repetition.

```
R command for the same is duplicated(sample$date). 
duplicated(sample$date)
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[22] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

To identify the unique observation we can also use unique(sample$date) in R.
```

We can do same for two variables `isid cost date`. Again, the `Stata` doesn't identify duplicate observations across two variables. The same is true when you use `unique(sample[,c(1,2)]` in `R`.

Again if I run `isid` on all four variables then `Stata` says that it is unique(no warnings).

```
duplicates example  cost date cap cum_n

Duplicates in terms of cost date cap cum_n

(0 observations are duplicates)
```

The same with `unique(sample)` in `R`.

**Conclusion**: I therefore, think that as long as one variable is unique (i.e. it has no duplicate observations), the combination of the variables which include the unique variable should be always unique. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: user1493368 has given a detailed example of `isid` in action. Note that `isid` is not really fundamental. It's a convenience command. One could go `bysort cost : assert _N == 1` and there would be silent consent (a return code `_rc` of 0) or `bysort date: assert _N == 1` and there would be an error message (a return code of 9).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused on a few points about `data.table`s and `key`s.

- A `data.table` will not have a key unless you explicitly set it.
- A `data.table` key does *not* have to be unique.

You can write a function that will check if certain columns could create a unique identifer for a dataset.

I've used data.table here, and have taken care to use `unique` on an unkeyed copy of the data.table.

This is *not* efficient.

```
 isid <- function(columns, data, verbose  = TRUE){
      if(!is.data.table(data)){
        copyd <- data.table(data)
      } else{ 
      copyd <- copy(data)
      }
     if(haskey(copyd)){
       setkey(copyd, NULL)
     }
    # NA values don't work in keys for data.tables
    any.NA <- Filter(columns, f= function(x) any(is.na(copyd[[x]])))
    if(verbose){
      for(aa in seq_along(any.NA)){message(sprintf('Column %s contains NA values', any.NA[aa] ))}
    }
    validCols <- setdiff(columns, any.NA)
    # cycle through columns 1 at a time
    ncol <- 1L
    validKey <- FALSE
    while(!isTRUE(validKey) && ncol <= length(validCols)){
      anyValid <- combn(x = validCols, m = ncol, FUN = function(xn){
        subd <- copyd[, ..xn]
        result <- nrow(subd) == nrow(unique(subd))
        list(cols = xn, valid = result)
      }, simplify = FALSE)

      whichValid <- sapply(anyValid, `[[`, 'valid')
      validKey <- any(whichValid)
      ncol <- ncol + 1L
    }

 if(!validKey){
 warning('No combinations are unique')
 return(NULL)} else {
   valid.combinations <- lapply(anyValid, `[[`, 'cols')[whichValid]
   if(length(valid.combinations) > 1){
    warning('More than one combination valid, returning the first only')
    }
    return(valid.combinations[[1]])
   }
 }
```

### some examples in use

```
 oneU <- data.table(a = c(2,1,2,2), b = c(1,2,3,4))
 twoU  <- data.table(a = 1:4, b = letters[1:4])
 bothU <- data.table(a = letters[1:2], b = rep(letters[1:2], each = 2))
 someNA <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,NA), b = 1:4)

isid(names(oneU), oneU)
# [1] "b"
isid(names(twoU), twoU)
# [1] "a"
# Warning message:
# In isid(names(twoU), twoU) :
#   More than one combination valid, returning the first only
isid(names(bothU), bothU)
# [1] "a" "b"
isid(names(someNA), someNA)
# Column a contains NA values
# [1] "b"

# examples with no valid identifiers

isid('a', someNA)
## Column a contains NA values
## NULL
## Warning message:
## In isid("a", someNA) : No combinations are unique
isid('a', oneU)
## NULL
## Warning message:
##  In isid("a", oneU) : No combinations are unique
```